# Detect the BuildType in Dotnet Core 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am looking to have a condition in my `.csproj` whereby I detect the buildType. Is there a property that gives me this information?

For example, I am wanting to detect when a build is triggered from `dotnet build` or `dotnet publish`

```
<Target Name="DebugRunWebpack" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition="'$(BuildType)' != 'publish'">
...
</Target>
```